# AngularJS ng-repeat destroy system font icons

Tags: css, angularjs

I've to develop something like this:

```
<span class="backletter" ng-repeat="letter in (CurrentMessage.Message) track by $index"> {{ letter }} </span>
```

I want to have each letter with a CSS style, it's like... a square per letter.

So, I've detected that if I use `ng-repeat`, my icons appear as a `?` and a diamond. If I "print" this like `{{ CurrentMessage.Message }}` it's displayed properly, but I need the other form.

How can I do that?

Comment: please provide more details regarding the question. Post the code you have tried

Comment: You controller and your template code would be useful, but it appears you're not telling Angular that letter contains trusted html content, so it gets encoded as text.